# Dividing a $10$ digit number to get a answer between $1$ and $13$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'd like to divide a $10$ digit number by any number between $2$ and $15$ and get any result between $1$ and $13$. That $10$ digit number has to contain the numbers from $0$ to $9$ and not repeat itself. (For example: $1,234,567,890$).

This $10$ digit number has to be divided by any number between $2$ and $15$ any number of times before finally getting an answer between $1$ and $14$. You cannot divide using a fraction nor get a fraction as an answer. An example of this is the $10$ digit number $2,143,968,750$. You can divide it by $15,\,15,\,15,\,15,\,14,\,11,\,11,\,5,\,5$ and get $1$ as an answer. I know there are about $35$ answers to this question but I'd like to find out how to get the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how you determine the sequence of divisions - just arbitrary?
And: what do you mean by "has to be devided by any number ..." - do you mean "by at least one" or "by all"?

Comment: Hi @oreilly! $$\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$$ Don't worry about it now (since you're new) but you might like to know that we prefer to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here $\ddot\smile$

Comment: simply means you only can divide the 10 digit number by any number (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 or 15) any number of times to get the result but not necessarily all of them individually to get the result wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's split this question into two parts:

**Part 1**

First is that you need a number that is a multiple of all numbers from 1 thru 13.

The easiest way to get a number which is a multiple of all numbers from 1 to 13 is $13! = 6227020800$, which has exactly 10 digits.

To get back the original number, just divide this with all numbers between $2..13$ except the expected number, e.g. to get 5 just do

$$6227020800 / (2*3*4*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13) = 5$$

To get other results you have to go down to number theory: your number cannot have any prime factors larger than 13 (like 17), as in that case no matter how many times you try to divide it by a factor smaller than 17, in the end the 17 will always remain in the result.

Now let's try to find all numbers, that can be used in this way. For that we know that the result has to contain $LCM(1,2,3,\dots,13) = 360360$, as this number is the lowest number from which you can get back all original numbers just by division. You can multiply this number with any other integer $n$ where the factors of $n$ does not contain prime numbers larger than 13 (this is to make sure the result won't contain new prime factors).

**Part 2**

Now let's go to the second part of the question: the result has to contain 10 digits, and each digit has to be unique.

I couldn't figure out an easy pure mathematical way to do this, but since the results set is qute low based on the results of the previous part, it can be calulated quickly by an algorithm:

```
let n = 1
while n * 360360 < 10^11          # has at most ten digits
  if n * 360360 >= 10^10 and      # has at least ten digits
     n does not contain factors larger than 13 and
     n * 360360 contains each digits only once then
     print n * 360360
  let n = n + 1
```

Here is a solution in ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
n = 1
while 360360 * n < 10000000000 do
  num = 360360 * n
  if num >= 1000000000 && n.gcd(360360) > 1 && n.prime_division.all?{|a|a[0]<=13} then
    ns = num.to_s.chars.sort
    if ns == ns.uniq then
      puts num
    end
  end
  n = n+1
end
```

Results:

```
none
```

According to this there are no results that satisy your condition. Note, the number you posted (2143968750) doesn't contain factor 4, so it's not possible to get the number 4 by just dividing the number.

**Part 3**

This probably means that the "get any result between 1 and 13" part of the original problem means that you don't need to actually get all of the numbers as a result. This makes the question both easier, as you only need a number which only contains prime factors of $2,3,5,7,11,13$, and harder, since now the numbers which you need to factorize is much larger.

To limit the amount of numbers which you want to factorize it might be easier to just check the factors of all numbers that are permutations of $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$

Algorithm:

```
for each permutation of 0..9 which doesn't start with 0:
   if the number got from the permutation has only prime factors lower than 13
       print out the number
```

Ruby code for this (note: this runs slow):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'prime'

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].permutation do |ns|
  next if ns[0]==0
  n = ns.join('').to_i
  if n.prime_division.all?{|a|a[0]<=13} then
    puts n
  end
end
```

Results:

```
1072963584
1243097856
1257389406
1280674395
1297836540
1379524608
1536809274
1745960832
2043916875
2134978560
2143709568
2143968750
2418609375
2561348790
3042571896
3409127568
3719048256
3725948160
3891240675
4153076928
4186932750
4235796180
4317806592
5210936874
5284071936
5364817920
6085143792
6195732480
6841209375
6973215480
7438096512
7451896320
8471592360
9487215360
9715064832
```

Comment: "That 10 digit number has to contain numbers from 0 to 9 and not repeat itself."

Comment: I think you have misread the question (which, admittedly, is not a model of clarity).

Comment: just wondering TonyK, why isn't it clear ?

Comment: @AlexR. fixed based on that

Comment: i just tried a few of your results but its doesn't work out right :) For example your first result 1427385960 can be divided by 13, by 11, by 10, by 9, by 7, by 4, but then i'm stuck at 3961 which cannot be divided by a number between 2 thru 13 anymore. The goal is to get a result below 14. Here's an example of a 10 digit number which works, 2143968750 can be divided by 15,15,15,15,14,11,11,5,5 and get 1 as an answer.

Comment: @oreilly: put up new results

Answer (score 0):

Since we're required to have a 10 digit number, there are $9*9!$ different 10 digit numbers using each of the numbers $0-9$ exactly once. This comes out to $3265920$ numbers. Of course, not all of these will be divisible by just the numbers below $15$.

Because 15 is not a prime, we don't actually need to test for divisibility by $15$, just at most $13$, and in fact setting the bounds to $16$ or $14$ would result in the exact same rules. For your example of $2143968750$, the simplest pattern of factorizations would be 2,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,7,11,11.

To create a number that has the highest chance of success, note a couple things: All of the 10-digit numbers created by these rules are divisible by $9$, and hence $3$ since the sum of the digits is 45, regardless of how you arrange them. If the last digit is 0, the number will be divisible by $10$, and hence $2$ and $5$. If the last three digits are divisible by $8$, then the entire number is divisible by 8 as well.

It would be relatively easy to create such a number programmatically by generating one of the 10-digit numbers and testing for divisibility, but there isn't a straight-forward, deterministic method for creating a number like that from scratch.

Comment: from what i can understand there is no math formula that can solve this problem but can only be done with a computer program. Perhaps so, i've resolved this problem some 30 years ago with a friend but i forgot how he did it! The only thing i know is that 2143968750 is an answer among the 35 or so answers.